# Batch, echo whole line from variable

Tags: batch-file

Reading from a text that looks like this:

```
10888982_I
90889156_I         8           2014-04-25 07:10:00           
10877565_I         17          2014-04-25 07:10:00
```

I am searching for content using the first column, variable %%i is set as the first column.  If not found it echo's to another text file.  It currently echos only the first column, how can I make it echo the entire line?  This is the script I am currently using

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (%src_folder%\spots.txt) DO (
  if EXIST %src_folder_hd%\%%i.mpg (
    xcopy "%src_folder_hd%\%%i.mpg" "%dest_folder%" /Y
  ) else (
    echo=%%i >> %src_folder%\missing.txt
  )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%src_folder%\spots.txt) do for /f %%B in ("%%A") do (
  if exist "%src_folder%\%%B" (
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%B" "%dest_folder%" /y
  ) else echo %%A>>"%src_folder%\missing.txt"
)
```

Note that the code assumes the file name never contains spaces.

Comment: Works great.  Exactly what I wanted with a minor tweak. I have others where the ID of the file are in the third or fourth column but I realized I can still use tokens in the 2nd for command to grab it that way.  Thanks.  For reference heres the adjusted script

for /f "delims=" %%A in (%src_folder%\spots.txt) do for "tokens=3" /f %%B in ("%%A") do (
  if exist "%src_folder%\%%B" (
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%B" "%dest_folder%" /y
  ) else echo %%A>>"%src_folder%\missing.txt"
)

Answer (score 0):

You set the option `tokens=1` so you only want the first token.
Change it to `tokens=*` or `delims=`, both will work for you

Comment: Wont work that way,  I have to search only by the first column for files I need.  But want to report the whole line of whats missing.

Comment: @user3500099 You are right, the correct solution is the one of dbenham